# why image not stretching verticlly

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-repeat

I have written the following code and I simply cannot understand why the image I have setted to be on the background doesn't strech vertically to cover the full page .
I would appreciate your help

```css
html{
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
html:after{
    margin-bottom:0;
    content : "";
    background: url("../images/van1.jpg") no-repeat center center;
    background-size:cover;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    z-index: -1;
}`
```

Comment: What do you more precisely mean by stretching? isn't this result ok? https://codepen.io/ekk0/pen/jQrYzW

Comment: Since that code sample _cover_ the full page, you need provide some more info what you mean by _stretch_.

Comment: Looks fine to me, covers the entire page when I run it locally.

Comment: As @Radu mentioned, isn't that result what you expected? If so, you might have a problem with the `Scrolling` wheels, and you thought your background doesn't stretch vertically because you see the `Scrolling` wheels... If I am true, you should remove `overflow-y: scroll;` from your `html` selector!

Comment: I probably should have added a link to let you know what I mean. Link to full code https://codepen.io/sissy_dk/pen/aQZXZj

Comment: why you're adding a child to html and not body? its like adding another child beside <body>. have you tried body:after? you should set height to 100% aswell

Comment: That link doesn't work, still, you are suppose to provide a [mcve] in the question, not use an external link alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `html:after` is like adding a child inside `<html>` beside your `<body>` tag, it's not valid and browsers may not render it correctly, it's better using `body:after` and set `height: 100%` so it covers your page.

Comment: change `margin: 2% 5% 2% 5%` to `padding: 2% 5% 2% 5%` and set margin to 0, because now we have to add extra space inside body and not outside.

Comment: ooh thanks so much! it would have taken my forever to find out!